# What is the number of square units in the area of the rectangle?

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me with this problem? I draw the graph according to the problem.

> The coordinates of one of the endpoints of a diagonal of a rectangle are (-4,2), and the coordinates of the point of intersection of the diagonals are (1,-1). The sides of the rectangle are parallel to the axes. What is the number of square units in the area of the rectangle?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  the diagonals intersect at the center of the rectangle.  You should be able to determine the coordinates of the lower right corner from that.  That gives you the sides of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can project to the lower right corner to get (6,-4), which will give you a top-right point of (6,2) and bottom-left of (-4,-4).  Now, subtract the corresponding coordinates to get the side lengths and multiply to get the area.